# Who has the winning hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em

The reads as follows 4 4 A J 6.
One player has a J 7.
Other has A 5. 
Who wins the hand? 
 Each player believes they have the winning hand, but which one does?

Answer (score 2):

Each player chooses the 5 best cards out of 7 cards (5 community cards + his own cards).
The first player (with J 7) choses  J J 4 4 A (two pair with A as kicker) and the second player (with A 5) chooses A A 4 4 J (two pair with J as kicker).

The second player wins because his highest pair (AA) is higher than player ones highest pair (JJ)